# Swift: how do I debug this poor performance?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the Master-Detail template and tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths is taking about 20-25 seconds to add a single row into the master view (after I add in my code). I'm new to iOS dev, so I'm wondering how I should diagnose this sort of perf issue.

When I step through the code, I can see that everything appears to complete quickly, but the app goes around and around in __NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish)_block_invoke

I realize this isn't much to go on. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
 let service = Service()
            service.getJson(url!) { (json, error) -> () in
                if error != nil && json != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    //return error!
                } else {
                    jsonResult = json
                    if let nameResult:AnyObject = jsonResult["name"] {

                        // Insert the new Board in the Master list
                        self.objects.insert(nameResult, atIndex: 0)
                        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

                     self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: Done, but not sure how helpful it will be. I've added tracing and each piece of code completes quickly. I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Could this be the umpteenth duplicate of "UI updates must be done on the main thread"?

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm new, but I've heard that. Thanks! At least I have something to look into now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martin R for getting this quickly. I wasn't forcing the UI updates to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

     self.objects.insert(nameResult, atIndex: 0)
     self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
     self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
```